# Making an Object Dependent Number of Fields for a Table in MS.Access

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to make a database that will hold a table of objects, and these objects are comprised of objects from a second table. One table is a table of possible sets, and the second is a table of possible components. The table of sets has to include fields for each of its components, but each set has an unknown number of components. How do I make a table with fields (Component 1, Component 2, Component 3, ...) that are dependent on each set to decide how many of the fields it needs?

Is there a way to do this just using the Access interface or will I actually have to get into the code behind it?

I think it would also solve my problem if there were a way to make a field in a column that acted as an ArrayList so if anyone could think of how to do that please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a component can be part of more than one set, what you need here is a [many-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29).

In a database you don't do this with an arbitrary number of columns, you use a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).

When you need a tabular representation, you use a Pivot / Crosstab query.

Your data model could look like this:

**Sets**

```
+--------+----------+
| Set_ID | Set_Name |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | foo      |
|      2 | bar      |
+--------+----------+
```

**Components**

```
+--------------+----------------+
| Component_ID | Component_Name |
+--------------+----------------+
|            1 | aaa            |
|            2 | bbb            |
|            3 | ccc            |
|            4 | ddd            |
+--------------+----------------+
```

**Junction table**

```
+----------+----------------+
| f_Set_ID | f_Component_ID |
+----------+----------------+
|        1 |              2 |
|        1 |              4 |
|        2 |              1 |
|        2 |              2 |
|        2 |              3 |
+----------+----------------+
```

(`f_` as in Foreign Key)

Comment: That's a much better solution than I've found elsewhere. Thanks.